# Consulta em array com mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Boa tarde amigos, pesquisei como fazer um find dentro de um array no mongodb, olhei a documentação e até aqui no fórum e não obtive resposta para minha duvida.

meu array ele não contem chaves relacionada a string:
Ex:  ["Nome1", "Nome2", "Nome3"]

E no mongo compass a visualização fica da seguinte forma

0:"Nome1"
1:"Nome2"
3:"Nome3"

`{dados_basicos: {$elemMatch: {"0":"Nome1"}}}`

não me retorna nada.

Olha minha estrutura:

```
{
    "_id": "XXX",
    "atuacao": {},
    "cpf": "XXX",
    "dados_basicos": {
        "idLattes": "XXX",
        "NUMERO-IDENTIFICADOR": "XXX",
        "DATA-ATUALIZACAO": {
            "$date": {
                "$numberLong": "1598812002000"
            }
        },
        "NOME-COMPLETO": "Claudio Miceli de Farias",
        "NOME-EM-CITACOES-BIBLIOGRAFICAS": ["FARIAS, C. M.", "Farias, Claudio M.", "Miceli, C.", "MICELI, C.", "MICELI, C", "DE FARIAS, CLAUDIO M.", "MICELI, CLAUDIO", "Miceli, Claudio", "Claudio de Farias", "DE FARIAS, CLAUDIO", "FARIAS, CLAUDIO", "FARIAS, CLAUDIO M. DE", "FARIAS, CLAUDIO MICELI DE", "MICELI DE FARIAS, CLAUDIO", "MICELI FARIAS, C."],
        "NACIONALIDADE": "B",
        "PAIS-DE-NASCIMENTO": "Brasil",
        "UF-NASCIMENTO": "RJ",
        "CIDADE-NASCIMENTO": "Rio de Janeiro",
        }
}
```

a minha duvida é conseguir buscar dentro desse array
`{dados_basicos: {$elemMatch: {"0":"FARIAS, C. M."}}}`
e me retornasse o documento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu tiver entendido certo, você precisa encontrar 1 ou mais documentos que contenham a expressão `FARIAS, C. M.` dentro do array `NOME-EM-CITACOES-BIBLIOGRAFICAS`.

Para ter acesso ao mesmo com o operador `$elemMatch`, você precisa especificar o caminho do objeto aninhado que contém esse array da seguinte forma:

```
# O '.' faz a ligação entre os campos do objeto raiz com o aninhado
dados_basicos.NOME-EM-CITACOES-BIBLIOGRAFICAS
```

E a query ficaria assim - para uma coleção genérica `collection`:

```
db.collection.find({
  "dados_basicos.NOME-EM-CITACOES-BIBLIOGRAFICAS": {
    $elemMatch: {
      $eq: "FARIAS, C. M."
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IFc9T-iPe5G)